# how to send data to backend without page reloading using ajax and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb

i want to send data to server side and save to mongodb, I try ajax but ajax is not working , actually I am posting comment on a post (blog website). i wnat without reloading form data should be save to sever side and come to client side. when I clicked button its says `Cannot POST /posts/611cf75d78929b0004bf439e`. but I have not place any action in form . is there any way to send data server side. also this is working with other page but not this plz share with me.

here is HTML form

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return doComment(this)">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= post.id %>" id="id" />
            <input type="text" name="name" id="input_value" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" required/>
            <textarea type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Write Comment Here" id="" required></textarea>
            <button >Post</button>
          </form>
```

here is javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function doComment(form){
        e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
      url:"/post/do-comment",
      method:"post",
      data:{name:form.name.value,comment:form.comment.value,
          _id:form._id.value},
      success: function(response){
      alert(response);
          }
      });
      return false;
  }</script>
```

here post router which is receive data and also comment schema save post id

```
app.post("/post/do-comment", async (req,res) =>{      
    console.log(req.body.name,req.body.comment)
    const comment = new Comment({name:req.body.name,comment:req.body.comment,post: req.body._id});
    await comment.save();
    await Post.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body._id}, {$push: {comment}});
    res.send("Comment was added successfully");
})
```

here is get route

```
app.get("/posts/:id", async (req,res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const post = await Post.findOne({ _id: id });
    const comments = await Comment.find({ post: id });
    const user = await User.findById({_id: post.user});

    console.log(user)
    console.log(post.user)
    res.render('posts', {
      post: post,
      comments: comments,
      user: user.name
    });
          
  });
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, when you submit the form do you receive the request on your backend? if you receive the requested date it means (ajax is working ), and the problem is you just need to prevent the UI to not render after submitting the form

Comment: Hi  Salah Ben Bouzid, no I do not receive any request or data in the backend

Comment: I would suggest using Axios, it's a great library  https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: thanks, let me try   : )